# How to properly truncate a float/decimal to a specific place after the decimal in python?

Tags: python, truncate

In Python 2.7.3, this is the current behavior:

```
>>> 8./9.
0.8888888888888888
>>> '%.1f' % (8./9.)
'0.9'
```

Same appears to be true for `Decimal`s:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(8) / Decimal(9)
Decimal('0.8888888888888888888888888889')
>>> '%.1f' % (Decimal(8) / Decimal(9))
'0.9'
```

I would have expected truncation, however, it appears to round.  So my options to truncating to the tenths place?

*FYI I ask because my current solution seems hacky (but maybe its the best practice?) as it make a string of the result, finds the period and simply finds X digits after the period that I want.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my options to truncating to the tenths place?

The [Decimal.quantize()](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize) method rounds a number to a fixed exponent and it provides control over the rounding mode:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_FLOOR
>>> Decimal('0.9876').quantize(Decimal('0.1'), rounding=ROUND_FLOOR)
Decimal('0.9')
```

Don't use [*math.floor*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/math.html#math.floor) on *Decimal* values because it first coerces them to a binary float introducing representation error and lost precision:

```
>>> x = Decimal('1.999999999999999999998')
>>> x.quantize(Decimal('0.1'), rounding=ROUND_FLOOR)
Decimal('1.9')
>>> math.floor(x * 10) / 10
2.0
```

Comment: I knew there was some nugget in there.  `.quantize()` is exactly what I was looking for.  For float's, it seems like the `math.floor()` is the only solution, but for `Decimal`'s, this is the **right** way.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the [`math.floor()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.floor) instead:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.floor(8./9. * 10) / 10
0.8
```

Comment: Ah you won by half a minute!

Comment: The *math.floor* function coerces its input to *float*, so it isn't a good choice for *Decimal* values.  The decimal module provides its own tools for truncation and rounding control.

Comment: This is still definitely very helpful (I +1'd it), however, in the case of `Decimal`s, Raymond's answer seems much better.

Comment: @dlamotte: Not a problem, that's what Stack Overflow is all about! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by 10, then floor the value.

In some language:

```
float f = 1/3;
print(f) //Prints 0,3333333333

float q = Math.floor(f*10)/10
print(q) //Prints 0,3
```